# Do not call destructors on incomplete objects (PHP 7.1 incompatible changes)

Tags: php, constructor, destructor, backwards-compatibility, php-7.1

[Do not call destructors on incomplete objects.](http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.incompatible.php#migration71.incompatible.dont-call-destructors)

> Destructors are now never called for objects that throw an exception during the execution of their constructor. In previous versions this behavior depended on whether the object was referenced outside the constructor (e.g. by an exception backtrace).

I'm doing the compatibility check for php 7.1, 7.2 and I do not how to check if I should fix something in the flow of the code for this case

I suppose:

1. Exception is called in the constructor.
2. The destructor (in some way implicitly) expected to be called in the code, because...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I think user-written destructors are not very common. So you only have to examine a class if it has a `__destruct()` method.

Then check its constructor, and make sure that it either never throws an exception, or it has its own `try/catch` that cleans up anything that the destructor would normally clean up for it.

I wouldn't worry about the part about it being conditional in previous versions. Just make sure that it works cleanly now.